# Cygwin Bash Script not throwing up any errors, but not working either

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am putting together a simple script to rename and copy files with a specific naming convention to a folder. I got the script all up and running on the linux machine I wrote it on, but once I switched over to the Windows 10 computer I need to run it off of, it stopped working.

I'm trying to run it off of Cygwin, and whenever I run it, Cygwin shows no errors or anything, but nothing happens. Not really sure where to head next...

Code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /cygdrive/c/path/to/files/*;
do
if [[ $file = *"Search_Criteria"* ]]; then
mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/KDM_//')";
fi
done
for file in /cygdrive/c/path/to/files/*;
do
if [[ $file = *"Search_Criteria"* ]]; then
cp "$file" "/cygdrive/c/File/Destination";
fi
done
```

Any suggestions on how to get this up and running on the Cygwin side of things would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The test as written in not effective, as the expansion does not work there.
You can check for a substring or just move the test as

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /cygdrive/c/path/to/files/*"Search_Criteria"* ;
do
    mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/KDM_//')";
fi
done
for file in /cygdrive/c/path/to/files/*"Search_Criteria"* ;
do
    cp "$file" "/cygdrive/c/File/Destination";
fi
done
```